# Makeindex error when ! used in \index in align environment

Tags: errors, amsmath, indexing, logging, imakeidx

See MWE below. The symbol `!` in the `\index` causes an error. This is only the case in `align` environments (not in `equation`). So it seems to have to do something with `amsmath`. If `!` is put in an `\mbox` there is no error. But then of course the font size is not adjusted to subindices. Curiously enough, `\index{$C_{K!!}$}` (two exclamation marks) doesn't cause any error.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y\index{$C_{K!}$}
\end{align}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

---

Any solutions suggested?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For makeindex the symbol `!` has a specific meaning.

The [manual of makeindex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) (`texdoc makeindex`) has the following example / explanation:

> To produce a subentry, the argument of the `\index` command should
>   contain both the main entry and the subentry, separated by a `!`
>   character.
>
> ```
> Page 7:  \index{gnat!size of}  || gnat, 32
> Page 32: \index{gnat}          ||     anatomy, 35
> Page 35: \index{gnat!anatomy}  ||     size of, 7
>          \index{gnus!good}     || gnus
> Page 38: \index{gnus!bad}      ||    bad, 38
>                                ||    good, 35
> ```

To print out the symbol `!` the manual shows

> To put a `!`, `@`, or `|` character in an index entry, quote it by preceding
>   the character with a `"`.

So the correct usage of your example is:

```
\begin{align}
y\index{$C_{K"!}$}
\end{align}
```

---

The quoted character can be changed my setting up the following line in the style file:

```
 quote '+'
```

Now the quoted character is `+`. E.g. for German language it's important than `"a` becomes `ä`.